# pyparsing: parse a sentence with special words in it

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to write a program with pyparsing that parse all strings contains special words in it. I wrote following code, but it is not working:

```
from pyparsing import *
word = Word(alphas) 
sentence = OneOrMore(word)
day = Literal("day")
sentence_end_with_happy = sentence + day + sentence 
ret = sentence_end_with_happy.parseString("hi this is a nice day and everything is ok")
```

I tried to parse a sentence with special word "day" but it has errors while parsing...

> pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "day" (at char 42), (line:1, col:43)

Comment: The rules for `sentence` consume everything to the end of the string including the word "day"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead when defining `word`; otherwise, `word` matches `day` and `sentence` will consume it.

```
from pyparsing import *
day = Keyword("day")
word = ~day + Word(alphas)
sentence = OneOrMore(word)
sentence_end_with_happy = sentence('first') + day + sentence('last') 
ret = sentence_end_with_happy.parseString("hi this is a nice day and everything is ok")
print ret['first']
print ret['last']
print ret
```

Output:

```
['hi', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'nice']
['and', 'everything', 'is', 'ok']
['hi', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'nice', 'day', 'and', 'everything', 'is', 'ok']
```

Comment: Extra points for using results names `first` and `last` to provide easy access to those parts of the output. Note to the OP - probably want to define `day` using `day = Keyword("day")`, else you will also match the leading part of words like `daybreak`, `days`, `daylight`, `daydream`, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Ah, good point, updated.  `pyparsing` is one of my favorite libraries and it is good to see the author so active on SO supporting it :).

Answer (score 0):

pyparsing is throwing exception because it is considering "day" as word in sentence.

In this case, you could use python built-in module [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) functions.

```
In [85]: str1 = "hi this is a nice day and everything is ok"
In [86]: str2 = "day"
In [87]: str2_pos = str1.find(str2)
In [88]: str1_split_str2 = [mystr[:str2_pos], mystr[str2_pos:str2_pos+len(str2)], mystr[str2_pos+len(str2):]]

In [89]: str1_split_str2
Out[89]: ['hi this is a nice ', 'day', ' and everything is ok']
```

Comment: thanks. but this is not my exact problem. I am writing a big project and I am using pyparsing for parsing book footnotes. and without handling the parsing of special words after some free word I could not use pyparsing well to handle different type of the footnotes. so I need a way handling the problem with pyparsing not solving it by python.